# All of a sudden, my text editor in Visual Studio is all sorts of crazy colors

Tags: visual-studio-2012

This happened all of a sudden - I have no idea what triggered it.  But, when I opened up a Visual Studio solution, here's what I get:

[image]

The text in blue and red aren't usually those colors, and the weird white border on the selected row isn't usually a border like this.  As you can see, it's kind of hard to read.  I can't recall exactly what colors they were, but they weren't these.  I went to the following and chose "Use Defaults", but that didn't do anything:

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed any extensions lately?

Comment: @jsve Well, guess that was it.  I installed Bing Code Search for C# (and I went in to disable it just now), and that resolved it.  Weird.  If you want to convert your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

An extension that you have recently installed might have caused this unexpected behaviour. Even seemingly unrelated extensions can sometimes do weird things.

If you've installed multiple extensions and don't know which one is the problem, try disabling them one by one and see if you can deduce which one is being problematic.

Comment: The problem was Bing Code Search Tool for C#.  I disabled it and problem went away.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution.